# getting bottom border without give bottom property in css what happen i can't understand

Tags: html, css

[image]

on bottom border how can I remove the bottom border on hover it's not removed by the CSS

```css
.bb-custom-wrapper>nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #524b96;
  /* #524b96  #1baede*/
  color: orange;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}

.bb-custom-wrapper>nav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.bb-custom-icon:before {
  font-family: 'arrows';
  /* speak: none; */
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: block;
  /* -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; */
}

.bb-custom-icon-first:before,
.bb-custom-icon-last:before {
  content: "\e002";
}

.bb-custom-icon-arrow-left:before,
.bb-custom-icon-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\e003";
}

.bb-custom-icon-arrow-left:before,
.bb-custom-icon-first:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="bb-nav-first" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-first">First page</a>
  <a id="bb-nav-prev" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-arrow-left">Previous</a>
  <a id="bb-nav-next" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-arrow-right">Next</a>
  <a id="bb-nav-last" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-last">Last page</a>
</nav>
```

here you can see i don't add any bottom border and in image you can see when i hover the button output represents the bottom border whats the problem i can't understand please me to find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a border, you can tell because it doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the element and it doesn't have the rounded corners from `border-radius`.

Try adding `text-decoration: none` to these links as a `:hover` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-decoration: none` to your `<a>`

```css
.bb-custom-wrapper>nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #524b96;
  /* #524b96  #1baede*/
  color: orange;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}

.bb-custom-wrapper>nav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.bb-custom-icon:before {
  font-family: 'arrows';
  /* speak: none; */
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: block;
  /* -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; */
}

.bb-custom-icon-first:before,
.bb-custom-icon-last:before {
  content: "\e002";
}

.bb-custom-icon-arrow-left:before,
.bb-custom-icon-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\e003";
}

.bb-custom-icon-arrow-left:before,
.bb-custom-icon-first:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a id="bb-nav-first" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-first">First page</a>
  <a id="bb-nav-prev" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-arrow-left">Previous</a>
  <a id="bb-nav-next" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-arrow-right">Next</a>
  <a id="bb-nav-last" href="#" class="bb-custom-icon bb-custom-icon-last">Last page</a>
</nav>
```

I have added `a,a:hover {text-decoration: none;}` to you code it seems to solve your bug.